# Python regex "and not"

Tags: python, regex

In Python, I want to split on a comma but not if it is followed by a trailing space

To split on the comma I have

`(?:[^,]+)`

Im looking for something like

```
(?:[^,]+)(?!:[^, ]+)
```

Example situation:

```
"Me, Myself & Irene,The Cable Guy"
```

should result in:

```
"Me, Myself & Irene"
"The Cable Guy"
```

Comment: Maybe, in this particular case, a positive lookahead would be preferable -
 `,+(?=[^\s,])`, but those are assumptions already.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I suspect the OP was using `re.findall()`, matching everything that is *not* a comma, and not `re.split()`. But then you'd have to use a more complicated regex, one where you include commas only if they are followed by a space.

Comment: True, so the fixed OP approach will be to use [`re.findall(r'[^,]+(?:,\s+[^,]+)*', s)`](https://regex101.com/r/PKTStV/1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want a negative look-ahead assertion, `(?!...)`. This matches any *position* that doesn't have the specified pattern following. To split on commas that are not followed by a space, that's:

```
,(?! )
```

For `re.split()` you don't need any other grouping.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r',(?! )', "Me, Myself & Irene,The Cable Guy")
['Me, Myself & Irene', 'The Cable Guy']
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain what is wrong with the original approach.

You were *matching* 1+ non-comma symbol chunks with `[^,]+`, and decided that if you add `(?!:[^, ]+)`, it will let you match the commas that are followed with commas. However, `(?:[^,]+)(?!:[^, ]+)` matches 1+ non-comma chunks that are not followed with `:` followed with 1 or more chars other than `,` and space.

What you really could try is matching a `,` that is followed with at least 1 whitespace and then again non-comma chunks, 0+ times:

```
re.findall(r'[^,]+(?:,\s+[^,]+)*', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PKTStV/1)

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/xObVox):

```
import re
rx = r"[^,]+(?:,\s[^,]+)*"
s = "Me, Myself & Irene,The Cable Guy"
print(re.findall(rx,s))
# => ['Me, Myself & Irene', 'The Cable Guy']
```

**However**, splitting with `,(?!\s)` is more efficient.